# Swap values in dropdown menus where both dropdowns contain the same values

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying recreate a feature found on a particular website, wherein the user can click on a button to swap the start location and the end location, so that entry in the start location dropdown value swaps with the end location dropdown value.

[image]

Initially this seemed quite straightforward to do (change the value of the selects), but if both dropdowns contain the same value, how would I point/update each dropdown with the respective matching item, instead of duplicating any dropdown entries by swapping the text around?

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option disabled="" selected="">Start</option>
            <option>Lab</option>
            <option>Hall</option>
            <option>Apartments</option>
            <option>Church</option>
            <option>Park</option>
            <option>College</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button>Swap</button><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option disabled="" selected="">End</option>
            <option>Lab</option>
            <option>Hall</option>
            <option>Apartments</option>
            <option>Church</option>
            <option>Park</option>
            <option>College</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e0x1jc43/1/

Comment: Why would you need to move text around? You're just changing the value of the selects.

Comment: we need your existing jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to move text around, just swap the values. Add `class="swapbutton"` to the Swap button, and use the following jQuery:

```js
$(".swapbutton").click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest(".row");
  var start = row.find("div.col-md-3:first select");
  var end = row.find("div.col-md-3:last select");
  var temp = start.val();
  start.val(end.val());
  end.val(temp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option disabled="" selected="">Start</option>
      <option>Lab</option>
      <option>Hall</option>
      <option>Apartments</option>
      <option>Church</option>
      <option>Park</option>
      <option>College</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button class="swapbutton">Swap</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option disabled="" selected="">End</option>
      <option>Lab</option>
      <option>Hall</option>
      <option>Apartments</option>
      <option>Church</option>
      <option>Park</option>
      <option>College</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```